How to merge two xml files at a specific level
I want to merge two xml files using Python:
File1.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<MyData>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <ElementID>15</ElementID>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</MyData>

And File2.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<MyData>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <ElementID>16</ElementID>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</MyData>

I can use the approach suggested in this Medium post:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree1 = ET.parse('File1.xml')
tree2 = ET.parse('File2.xml')
root1 = tree1.getroot()
root2 = tree2.getroot()
root1.extend(root2)
tree1.write('merged_files.xml')

This returns:
<MyData>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <ElementID>15</ElementID>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
<Elements>
    <Element>
      <ElementID>16</ElementID>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</MyData>

But how can I merge files at a given "level", e.g. Elements?
I would like to obtain:
<MyData>
  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <ElementID>15</ElementID>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <ElementID>16</ElementID>
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</MyData>


It is a trivial task for XSLT 3.0 It has a built-in Merge statement that allows to merge unlimited number of XML files. Are you up to it?

Thanks for letting me know about XSLT @YitzhakKhabinsky.

Can the task that you have in mind be performed using Python's lxml library, then?

You would need to use Saxon for that: https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml

This can easily be done in XSLT 1.0  using document() function which lxml supports. If your actual XML is more complex than post, consider this approach.

Extending Elements on first file with all Element from second file
root1 = tree1.getroot()
root2 = tree2.getroot()
root1.find('Elements').extend(root2.findall(".//Element"))
tree1.write('merged_files.xml')


Thanks for your answer @LMC. root2.findall("Element") returns an empty list but using root2.findall(".//Element") did the trick.

I have found a method that is finding Elements tag of first xml and append the all children of the second xml Elements's data to it
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

first_tree = ET.parse('File1.xml')
first_root = first_tree.getroot()

second_tree = ET.parse('File2.xml')
second_root = second_tree.getroot()

first_elements = first_root.find('Elements')
second_elements = second_root.find('Elements')

"""Merges the 'Elements' nodes from two XML files into a single XML file. 
   This code iterates through the 'Elements' 
   nodes in the second XML file and appends them to the 'Elements' in 
   the first XML file. It then writes the merged 
   XML tree to a new file named 'MergedFile.xml'."""
for elem in second_elements:
    first_elements.append(elem)

first_tree.write('MergedFile.xml', encoding='ASCII', 
xml_declaration=True)

merged_tree = ET.ElementTree(first_root)
ET.dump(merged_tree)

I'll hope this would be helpful

Thanks for your detailed answer @Eshan Shavandi.

I got very close to your solution but mistakenly tried calling write on an xml.etree.ElementTree.Element object, whereas you successfully use this method on first_tree, which is an xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.
